# Set method when instance is created

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to execute the set method when an instance is created?. I have this piece of code:

```js
class CoffeeMachine {
  _power;
  
  constructor(power) {
    this._power = power;
  }
  
  set power(value) {
    if (value < 100) {
      this._power = 100;
    }
  }
  
  get power() {
    return this._power;
  }
}

// create the coffee machine
let machine = new CoffeeMachine(90);
console.log(machine)
```

I know that if I set "power" to public the setter is executed but I need it to be a protected property. Power is still 90 even it's less than 100, so it doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: `_power` and `power` are both public. You probably wanted something like `#_power;`.

Comment: Why not just use `this.power = power;` in the constructor?

Comment: machine.power = someNewValue

Comment: The setter is quite strange: if the value is 100 or more it does not do anything.

Comment: why don't you directly implement ```constructor(power) {
    if (power < 100) {
      this.power = 100;
    } else {
      this._power = power;
    }
  }``` in consturctor

Comment: @Nikkkshit logic in two places, not a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `this._power = power;` in the constructor to `this.power = power;`, because there isn't a setter placed on `_power`. If you set `power`, it should call the setter.

```js
class CoffeeMachine {
  _power;
  
  constructor(power) {
    this.power = power; // ***
  }
  
  set power(value) {
    if (value < 100) {
      this._power = 100;
    }
  }
  
  get power() {
    return this._power;
  }
}

// create the coffee machine
let machine = new CoffeeMachine(90);
console.log(machine)
```

As a side note, you could make `_power` private by making it `#power` (see the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) for more info).

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing your setter logic is not supposed to be over the power level of 100. You are not setting the value when the cause is valid. You should be setting `power` in the constructor and not the private property directly.

I added logging to show the things being called.

```js
class CoffeeMachine {
  #power;
  
  constructor(power) {
    console.log(`contructor called with value ${power}`);
    this.power = power;
  }
  
  set power(value) {
    console.log(`setter called with ${value}`);
    this.#power = value > 100 ? 100 : value;
    console.log(`power set to ${this.#power}`);
  }
  
  get power() {
    console.log(`getter called, returning ${this.#power}`);
    return this.#power;
  }
}

// create the coffee machine
let machine = new CoffeeMachine(90);
console.log(1, machine.power);

machine.power = 1000;
console.log(2, machine.power);
```

If you do not want a public setter, then do not add one.

```js
class CoffeeMachine {
  #power;
  
  constructor(power) {
    console.log(`contructor called with value ${power}`);
    this.#updatePower(power);
  }
  
  #updatePower(value) {
    console.log(`setter called with ${value}`);
    this.#power = value > 100 ? 100 : value;
    console.log(`power set to ${this.#power}`);
  }
  
  get power() {
    console.log(`getter called, returning ${this.#power}`);
    return this.#power;
  }
}

// create the coffee machine
let machine = new CoffeeMachine(90);
console.log(1, machine.power);

machine.power = 1000;  // ignored
console.log(2, machine.power);
```